# How can I add text to a text area at the bottom right of the text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, textarea

I want to show the user how many allowable characters they have left to type, and I would like to place this within the text area, at the bottom right, after a new line; refreshing it after the textarea has changed in anyway. I just need help on placing it in said position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function countChar(val){
     var len = val.value.length;
  
     if (len >= 50) {
              val.value = val.value.substring(0, 50);
     } else {
              $('#charNum').text(50 - len);
     }
};
```

```css
.main{
  position: relative;  
  display: inline-block;
}
.main textarea{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  resize: none;
}
.main span{
  color: coral;
  position: absolute;  
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <textarea class="textareatest" onkeyup="countChar(this);"></textarea>
  <span id="charNum">50</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this you expecting

Comment: Thanks alot. I was too focused on manipulating the text *inside* the textarea, and didn't think of adding a div outside and using absolute positioning... This basically it, but I'm making the text area look like a single line input and I need a newline to appear at the bottom when the number is shown (its shown after x characters), and remain constantly until the text is within limits; sorry if this wasn't 100% clear above. How can I keep a new line at the bottom so that the text in textarea doesn't crash into the charNum? A good example is quora's question field.

Comment: I figured out the last part; Im just going to increase the padding on the text area to create the "newline". Thanks for the answer; I'm not sure why people are handing out downvotes to everyone... I gave everyone a 1+ to offset that.

Comment: Some where using this as fun area Jaigus , One don't know the importance of suffering only downvote or else they would have asked for clear description of question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with something like this.

```js
function count(){
  document.getElementById('textarea').onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = this.value.length;
};
  }
```

```css
.main{
  position: relative;  
  display: inline-block;
}
.main textarea{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px;
  resize: none;
}
.main span{
  color: coral;
  position: absolute;  
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <textarea id="textarea" onclick="count()"></textarea>
  <span id="count">0</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do someting like this:

```
<div class="form-block">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <div class="label"></div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.form-block {
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made This using bootstrap and jquery.

```
<div style="margin-top:45px; margin-left:45px">
<form>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class='textCountContianer'>
    <label>Some Text</label>
    <div class="count">0/250</div>
    <textarea class='form-control' type="text" maxlength="250"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.count{
position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 10px;
  color:gray
}
.textCountContianer{
  position: relative;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
  var textlen = $(this).attr('maxlength') - $(this).val().length;
  $(this).parent().find('.count').html('<span>'+$(this).val().length+'/'+$(this).attr('maxlength')+'</span>');
});
```

Demo
https://codepen.io/badevellis/pen/mdwWXLq